# How to select min and max in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to convert this code in laravel.

```
SELECT MAX(date_start) AS DateStart,MIN(date_end) AS DateEnd FROM DBTest
```

And I try this code

```
$data = DB::table('DBTest')
    ->select(max('date_start'), min('date_end')))
    ->get();
```

Return Error: max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

I am using laravel 5.2, and SQLyog as database

I am confuse in syntax please help me

Comment: check my answer. it's so much easier than you think :)

Comment: those `max()` and `min()` methods are not related to DB queries, they just return the max and min of an array. to use database functions, you need to use `\DB::raw('...')` or `selectRaw(...)`(if it's in the select part)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use functions in select statement, but you can use raw SQL :

```
$data = DB::table('DBTest')
   ->select(\DB::raw('MIN(date_start) AS DateStart, MAX(date_end) AS DateEnd'));
   ->get();
```

Comment: `->select(\DB::raw('MIN(date_start) AS DateStart, MAX(date_end) AS DateEnd'));` getting min value and max value are working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

For the max start date:

```
max = DB::table('DBTest')->select('date_start')->orderBy('date_start', 'desc')->first();
```

For min end date:

```
 min = DB::table('DBTest')->select('date_end')->orderBy('date_end', 'asc')->first();
```

Comment: @MathewMagante nice surprise after more then a year, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use something called `selectRaw` method in Laravel in order to achieve this result. Chaining method like `->max('columnA')->min('columnB')` will not work. So, here is the solution:

```
$data = DB::table('DBTest')
->selectRaw('MAX(date_start) AS DateStart, MIN(date_end) AS DateEnd')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions in the sql query.

```
$data = DB::table('DBTest')
  ->select(\DB::raw('MIN(date_start) AS startDate, MAX(date_end) AS endDate'));
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use DB::raw with Select Statement**

return DB::table('DBTest')
->Select(DB::raw("max(date_start) as New_date,min(date_end) as date_end"))->get();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).